# EXM 3 Sitecore 8: Invalid object name 'dbo.Fact_AutomationStatesStatisticsByMessage' after Setup

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ecm, sitecore-exm

After installing a clean sitecore 8 and the EXM module, I get the following exception when trying to create a new one-time-message:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Fact_AutomationStatesStatisticsByMessage'.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you run Sitecore.EmailExperienceManager.sql to create the necessary tables in the reporting database of your instance. The file is available in the Data folder.

Answer (score 1):

During the installation process of the EXM module important-post-installation-steps are shown, also there is a site from sitecore explaining the steps:

https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/setting_up_exm/configuration/configure_the_exm_for_the_first_time

Comment: Link now https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/setting_up_exm/configuration/configure_the_exm_for_the_first_time